# OpenJPA prevent Table from being build

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Im currently using OpenJPA for my project.
Normally I want OpenJPA build the tables corresponding to my entities automatically, but I also have one Entity which only carries an Attribute for a primary key of a table which already exists.
Because of this uncomplete representation of the table I would like to prevent JPA from trying to build this table.

I just red that there is a "@Subselect"-Annotation in Hibernate which should allegedly prevent it from creating the table. Is there an equivalent in OpenJPA?

Comment: I am not common with OpenJPA, but it looks like it only create tables for classes which are annotated with `@Entity`

Comment: I knew that, but I am afraid I cant declare values of this table as Foreign Key in another Entity, as long as it isnt annotated with "@Entity", or am I wrong?

Comment: If I get your structure correctly, you have a class, whose PK is outsourced into another class. In hibernate this is done with `@EmbeddedId` and `@Embeddable`. These seem to exist in OpenJPA too. Maybe you should take a look at those